# Void of life- what is this

Tags: riddle

I am devoid of life.
I eat at your warmth.
I take your comfort.
I leave nothing.
Come to the plain where I lurk,
and you will be incased in cold.
I am infinite yet no one knows what I am,
and you'll be choked out before you know it.
What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am

> A singularity / black hole

It is devoid of life,

> Certainly

It takes away your warmth / encases you in cold

> True, due to the excessive gravity it absorbs any type of radiation including light therefore any form of heat and in the space near it there's near absolute cold

It leaves practically nothing,

> True, it assimilates anything.

It is Infinite,

> True, no amount of size/mass limitation has been proven to exist

No one knows

> True, mostly the science of it is based on assumptions and cannot be practically tested

And chokes you out before you know it.

> Definitely ...

Comment: Well done! You got it right

Comment: Thank you. I usually think of more abstract things.

Answer (score 1):

I guess

> it could be space(to be precise- evacuated space)

which

> is infinite, devoid of life, is cold, and can be mysterious enough fitting the description.

Though

> this is a partial one!

Answer (score 1):

Is it maybe

> time?

I am devoid of life.
I eat at your warmth.
I take your comfort.
I leave nothing.

> As time is passing, we are loosing life, warmth, and comfort.

Come to the plain where I lurk,
and you will be incased in cold.

> Honestly, not so sure about this part...

I am infinite yet no one knows what I am

> Time is infinite, it is hard to define.

and you'll be choked out before you know it

> Everybody dies. Sooner or later we are out of time.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it

> Wind

its devoid of life

Take away your warmth

leave practically nothing

and of course, infinite

Comment: "yet no one knows what I am" - I'm pretty sure people know what rot13(jvaq) is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> Death

It is devoid of life,

It takes away your warmth

> The body goes cold after death

It leaves practically nothing,

It is Infinite,

And chokes you

> out of breath